# Create formula to count the number of times a name appears in one column and a answer in the second column multiplied by a number

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have 2 columns in my worksheet that has a name and location. I want to count the number of times a name and location appear and then multiply it by a number.  Here's my example
Erin can go to "LA", "TONU", "IE" during the week for each LA he gets 350*33%.  Here's the formula I'm trying to use what am I doing wrong?

=COUNTIFS((B1:B1000,"Erin",C1:C1000,"LA")*(350*33%)+(B1:B1000,"Erin",C1:C1000,"TONU")*(50))+(B1:B1000,"Erin",C1:C1000,"IE")*(400*33%))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the calculations and the counts together. They need to be separated out:

`=COUNTIFS(B1:B1000,"Erin",C1:C1000,"LA")*350*33%+COUNTIFS(B1:B1000,"Erin",C1:C1000,"TONU")*50+COUNTIFS(B1:B1000,"Erin",C1:C1000,"IE")*400*33%`

Perhaps consider putting the `COUNTIFS` calculation for each place in a separate cell and then adding the values in those 3 cells together. It will make debugging and checking your worksheet much easier. The longer the formula the harder it is to check and correct.